# Book about spiders whose bite is deadly, but surviving the bite creates immortality?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, immortality

Does anyone know a book about spiders whose bite is deadly, but when people kill them all, they discover that surviving the bite creates immortality?

It may be a short story, I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about it, like when you read it, language it was written in, etc. Also, if the bite is deadly how could you survive it?  Did the bite kill less than 100% of the people bitten?

Comment: It's at least 40 years old. My mom has been looking for it for 2 decades. And I think one person finally survived what was preciously always fatal for them to find out. I'm not positive though.

Comment: @NiallC. a gunshot is deadly but many, many people survive them. Ebola is deadly but can be treated. Etc.

Comment: *Spider-Bite* by Robert Carr features spiders whose bite can resurrect the dead.

Answer (score 6):

Not a spider, but you could be thinking of "Healer" by F Paul Wilson --

"Steven Dalt should have died in that cave on the planet Kwashi. After
all, as the natives say, **of a thousand people attacked by the
cave-dwelling alaret, nine-hundred-and-ninety-nine will die.** Dalt
survives, but not without personal cost: he has picked up a passenger: an
alien intelligence transferred itself from the alaret to take up residence
in his brain. Steven Dalt will never be alone again. But Pard, as Dalt
names the alien who shares his life, doesn't believe in freeloading. He
pays his rent by using cellular-level consciousness to maintain Dalt's
body in perfect health" no disease, no aging. And now Dalt appreciates the
full meaning of the Kwashi natives saying: Of a thousand struck down by an
alaret, nine-hundred-and-ninety-nine will die. But the thousandth will not
die . . . ever. Spanning twelve hundred years, HEALER follows Dalt and
Pard through the centuries as they become known as The Healer, an
enigmatic figure with the power to cure diseases of the mind. And when a
wave of interstellar slaughter threatens the civilizations of the LaNague
Federation, only The Healer has the resources to face the onrushing doom."