# Book about a man who enters a cave on an alien world and a parasite merges with him?

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

The main character gains psychic abilities when he enters a cave on an alien world and a parasite merges with him. Subsequent eeg scans show he has two traces, one normal, his own, and a second which has all the psychic abilities, his parasite. It's not much to go on, other details are fuzzy and may only confuse the issue if they are from a different book.

Comment: You've provided some good plot details, however adding things like when you read it, and character names, what the cover may have looked like all help us to help you. Take a look at [this checklist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details

Comment: Please, when writing questions do not use generic titles like "question about a book", which tells a potential reader nothing. Include some details in the title! (I've fixed it now)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question:https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103919/what-is-the-name-of-this-book-symbiosis-in-cave-between-man-and-alien/103924#103924

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like it might be 'Healer' by F Paul Wilson.

The second mind in his head comes from a cave creature that drops from the roof of the cave and joins with whichever type of animal that has wandered in. The symbiote gains the same intelligence as the host animal.

There is also a quotation that is floating about in my memory - 'Of every 100 people that are attacked by the cave creature 99 of them will die'. Then it goes on to say that the 100th will not die. The symbiote can effectively make its host immortal....

Comment: This would be my guess, the parasite dropping on him occurs right at the start.

Comment: This sounds very promising, the 99/100 line sounds very familiar too. I didn't give you much to go on, I was afraid other details may have actually been from a different book so only included what I was certain of. Now to find it and reread it, then I'll know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like Dan Simmons' "Hyperion", [Part One, The Priest's Tale: "The Man who Cried God"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_(Simmons_novel)#Part_One,_The_Priest's_Tale:_%22The_Man_who_Cried_God%22).

I'm still not sure we can call what Father Duré got a psychic ability, but at least some action happens in the cave.