# Story about a man who got bonded to a symbiote alien

Tags: story-identification

It's about a man who got bonded to a symbiote alien and got abilities like he could heal himself and other stuff, it also gave him a patch of silver hair. It's a series, the last of the series, I think, ended when he had to help fight off an invasion of aliens controlled telepathically.

Comment: I've created a better title for this post as the initial one wasn't helpful at all. Could you also take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example, you say series was it a books or a TV show? When did you see this? Was it new at the time? Etc.

Comment: There are some similarities to Brian Stableford's "Hooded Swan" series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooded_Swan

Comment: Very probable dupe to this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181887/book-about-a-man-who-enters-a-cave-on-an-alien-world-and-a-parasite-merges-with. He has the patch of silver hair from where the parasite landed on his head. However not a series, but a collection of stories in the book.